# How can I programmatically add a text field with a decimal pad keyboard in Xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I needed to add a UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad keyboard to a decimal field, which can only be done programatically.  I need the full code (I'm pretty new to Objective-C) to make a UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad pop up when someone touches inside the text box.  I'd also like to add the text field programmatically.
Basically, I need to add a text field with a UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad keypad.  Or, if possible, just the keypad to a text field made in Interface Builder.

Does anyone know a good tutorial for this or can anyone give me the full code themselves, and tell me where I need to put it (the .m or .h or what?)?

**Thanks!**

Update: As mentioned in the comment below, could I see example code for an app that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the keyboard type to UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad, just assign that value to the text field's `keyboardType` property.

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
```

Adding a text field programmatically is only slightly more work: `UITextField *textField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];` to create it, then set any properties you need to set, and add it to the appropriate view with `addSubview:`.

In your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method is a good place for this sort of thing. Or if you're loading a view without a controller from the nib, use the view's `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I'd give you a thumbs up if the site let me.  Sadly, I still don't quite get the whole thing.  Could you like show me a little example code?  Like maybe the last part of a file, just making the text field?  I need to know which particular code file to put it in and where to put it though.  sorry, I feel really stupid. :(

Comment: @Objective: You can give a "thumbs up" by clicking on the check mark next to this answer if it solved your problem for you.

Comment: @ObjectiveProgrammer: You probably already have a UIViewController subclass corresponding to the nib you designed in IB, and in IB the text field in question connected to an outlet. If you don't already have one, implement `- (void)viewDidLoad`. It will need only two lines: one a call to `[super viewDidLoad]`, and the other the setting of `keyboardType` described above.

Comment: @Josh: Lol, didn't realize.  I am new here.